# The code is slower after every iteration and doesnt give expected output

Tags: tensorflow

I need to perform the following tasks for 3 identical neural networks (identical in architecture, not parameters) - A,B,C

1. Update Weights of C as a function of A and B
2. Train C
3. Update Weights of A,B based on new (trained weights of C)
4. Update the values of masking arrays

I am very new to Tensorflow and can't figure out how to do these operations sequentially. Here is the code I came up with

```py
#Step 3
ass=(W1a.assign((W1c* trans_arr1)+(W1a*(tf.ones([784, L]-trans_arr1)))))

#Step 1
a1=W1c.assign((W1a*trans_arr1)+(W1b*(tf.ones([784, L])-trans_arr1))))

#Step 4
trans_arr1 = genRandMat(784,L,ptrans)

#Loop
for i in range((400)+1):

    #Train C

    training_step(i, i % 100 == 0, i % 20 == 0)

    # Update weights of A,B based on new weights of C

    sess.run([ass])

    #Update masking array

    sess.run([trans_arr1])

    #update C based on A,B
    sess.run([a1])
```

Note - trans_arr is the masking matrix with 1's and 0's, 1 present with a probability ptrans at every position

This isn't giving the expected results, suggesting operations are not running in the order in which I want them to. How can I achieve the desired result? Any suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't shared all of your code its a bit tough to think what exactly might be going wrong, but here are a few things you might want to check.

1. Make sure your genRandMat function is actually generating a new random matrix after every iteration. Keep in mind if it uses the numpy or other APIs instead of Tensorflow then it might not do what you expect to. Try looking into tf.Variable.load() if you are indeed using other APIs to serve this purpose.\
2. To run operations sequentially you might consider looking into Eager Execution mode of tensorflow, though having limited experience in it myself I cant recommend it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, also a quick PS - its usually a good idea to avoid such 'wall of code' questions. Since you are new here you might also want to read this article on [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)